# FIltrations on a vector bundle on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a smooth connected projective curve of genus $g$ over an algebraically closed field. 
Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $X$ of rank $n$. 
Is it true that there exists a constand $N(g,n)$ such that each such $E$ has a filtration
$$
0\subset E_1\subset ...\subset E_n=E
$$
by subbundles with $rank(E_i)=i$, such that $deg(E_i/E_{i-1})-deg(E_{i+1}/E_i)\geq N(g,n)$ ?
What is the reference for this?

Comment: This reminds me the Harder-Narashiman filtration, where
$$\mu(E_i/E_{i-1}) > \mu(E_{i+1}/E_i)$$
and $\mu(F) :=\deg(F) / \textrm{rank}(F)$ is the slope.

Comment: Well, it has something to do with Harder-Narasimhan, but it is not quite that. For example, if $n=2$ then the statement is that any rank 2 bundle has a line sub-bundle whose degree is not too small.

Comment: Do you mean to assume $n > 1$?

Comment: Yes, if you wish (otherwise the question is empty)

Comment: I must be missing something, we have rank two (semi-)stable bundles of arbitrary negative degree. So you can not bound the degree of the line sub-bundles from below universally. Do you want a bound that depends on $g$, $n$, and the degree?

Comment: No, the point is that if $E$ has rank 2 then the claim is that we can find a line subbundle $E_1$ of $E$ such that $deg(E_1)-deg(E/E_1)$ is not too small (I think you can always make it smaller than $g$ in this case) -- this is true even when the degree of $E$ is very negative.

Comment: I guess this might be the motivation of your question, but for a curve over a finite field this is a consequence of reduction theory, i.e. I think it is precisely the translation of the fact that a "Siegel set" contains a fundamental domain. For that, there is an article of Springer "Reduction theory over global fields."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to lemma 4 of

M.F. Atiyah, *Vector bundles over an elliptic curve*,  Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 7 (1957), 414-452.

you could take $N(g,n) = - 2 g$.

Comment: You can think of this as an example of "bend-and-break".  If you denote by $(\pi:P\to X,\pi^*E\to \mathcal{O}_P(1))$ the universal invertible quotient of the pullback of $E$, then the problem is to give an upper bound on the $\mathcal{O}_P(1)$-degree of a section.  Since $\omega_\pi$ is $\pi^*\text{det}(E)\otimes\mathcal{O}_P(-\text{rank}E)$, and since bend-and-break breaks sections until their anticanonical degree is at most $2$, this precisely gives that the minimal $\mathcal{O}_P(1)$-degree of a section is no greater than $(\text{deg}(E)+2g)/\text{rank}(E)$.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the reference I was looking for.